# The table name is too long to be displayed completely in TDengine

Tags: tdengine

I am running TDengine database.

As you can see in the image, when I execute `show tables`, some table names are too long to be displayed completely.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBbao.jpg)

Does anyone know how to display them completely?

Answer (score 0):

it is configurable in TDengine config file: /etc/taos/taos.cfg

```
# maximum display width of binary and nchar fields in the shell. The parts exceeding this limit will be hidden
# maxBinaryDisplayWidth 30
```

just change 30 to a proper value and don't forget to remove the pound (#) to make it work